# Prevent FormControl Angular Directive set select tag as no value

Tags: angular, typescript

I´m saving my form with `FormControl` and `FormGroup` Directives, but when I declare the object, it sets as no value on `<select>`

This is my component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-user',
  templateUrl: './new-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})

export class NewUserComponent implements OnInit {
  data: FormGroup;
}

ngOnInit(){
  this.data = new FormGroup({
   name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required ),
   city: new FormControl( null, Validators.required )
  })
}

sendData() {
 console.log( this.data.value );
}
```

This is my HTML

```
<form (ngSubmit)="sendData()" [formGroup]="data">
  <input formControlName="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="name">
  <select formControlName="city" name="city">
    <option selected disabled>Select a city</option>
    <option value="1">Russia</option>
    <option value="2">Spain</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

The logic works fine, but when the page is reloaded, the select is totally with no value, is in blank ( not even "Select a city" ) how could I solve it?

I tried

```
city: new FormControl()
```

And still with the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the attribute `[value]=null` in the default item you want to be selected.

```
<select formControlName="city" name="city">
    <option selected disabled [value]="null">Select a city</option>
    <option value="1">Russia</option>
    <option value="2">Spain</option>
  </select>
```

Have a look at this as well https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ay1dgr

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  <select formControlName="city" name="city">
    <option [value]="null" disabled>Select a city</option>
    <option [value]="1">Russia</option>
    <option [value]="2">Spain</option>
  </select>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bv2ueg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html